# PDF generation — How to merge multiple stream objects?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm currently into generating PDF documents **without the use of an external library** and it has been going well so far. I've written the document exposed below with a text editor (*vim*) and it renders the expected results using at least two PDF distinct viewers (*evince* & *gsview*, running Linux).

This document produces three squares at top of the page, coming in different sizes, widths and colors.

My question is : **is there a way to merge two stream objects into a new single one** or, in other words, is there a way to compose sophisticated objects starting from simple ones, so we can easily refer to these composite objects, multiple times if needed ?

In the given example, object `5 0 obj` is drawing a square, and following ones are just applying colors and coordinates transformations (through a matrix).

The PDF reference manual states that multiple stream contents passed as an array to page object's `/Contents` parameter are concatenated and processed as a single continuous stream, which totally does the trick… as long as the document remains small and simple!

In this same example, the `/Contents` array is indirectly passed through object `4 0 obj`, which refers three times to `5 0 R`, to draw the squares.

The ideal here would be to define three differents objects, each refering to `5 0 R` by themselves, then invoke only these objects, a single time each, from the `Contents` array.

I tried adding **subarrays** inside it, which could in turn be embedded into dedicated objects and referenced indirectly, but it unfortunately doesn't work. :-(

A lot of thanks to any people that could/try-to help !

PS: I'm doing it because I'm interested in the format itself and would like to produce some autogenerated documents from small scripts. Also, I'll probably embed them into a weakly powered appliance and I cannot afford relying on dozens of megabytes in dependencies.

But before this, I still tried to do that too, using **PHP** with **TCPDF**. If there's already some facilities dedicated to this that I would have missed, this is relevant to my interests too. :-)

---

**Small.pdf** (hand made PDF file)

```
%PDF-1.7

1 0 obj
<<
    /Type       /Catalog
    /Pages      2 0 R
>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<<
    /Type       /Pages
    /Count      1
    /Kids       [ 3 0 R ]
>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<<
    /Type       /Page
    /MediaBox   [ 0.000000 0.000000 1000.000000 1414.213562 ]
    /Contents   4 0 R
>>
endobj

4 0 obj
% A simple array, just to avoid embedding it directly in /Page object (3 0 R here)
[
    6 0 R   5 0 R   % Red   square
    7 0 R   5 0 R   % Green square
    8 0 R   5 0 R   % Blue  square (tilted)
]
endobj

5 0 obj
% Draws a square, centered by default on lower left corner
<<
    /Length     43
>>
stream
+20 +20 m
+20 -20 l
-20 -20 l
-20 +20 l s Q
endstream
endobj

6 0 obj
<<
    /Length     63
>>
stream
/DeviceRGB CS
q
1.0 0.0 0.0 SC
2.0 w
1 0 0 -1 60 1354.213562 cm
endstream
endobj

7 0 obj
<<
    /Length     49
>>
stream
q
0.0 1.0 0.0 SC
1.0 w
2 0 0 -2 190 1334.213562 cm
endstream
endobj

8 0 obj
<<
    /Length     83
>>
stream
q
0.0 0.0 1.0 SC
5.0 w
0.707106781 0.707106781 -0.707106781 0.707106781 110 1250 cm
endstream
endobj

xref
0 9
0000000000 65535 f
0000000010 00000 n
0000000079 00000 n
0000000168 00000 n
0000000296 00000 n
0000000513 00000 n
0000000674 00000 n
0000000796 00000 n
0000000905 00000 n
trailer
<<
    /Size       9
    /Root       1 0 R
    /ID         [ <0000000000> <0000000001> ]
>>
startxref
01047
%%EOF
```

Comment: What you are looking for are form XObjects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I indeed stumbled on it but I misled myself afterward, thinking it was something totally different. The explanation is probably to be taken from the documentation too : "_Note: The term form also refers to a completely different kind of object, an inter-
active form (sometimes called an AcroForm)_". I'll try and let you know if it works. In the meantime, can you redact an answer so I can validate yourself ? Thanks.

Comment: It does work. I've been finally able to produce a hand-made PDF using XObjects. Thanks a lot.

Can you just write a short but official answer so I can validate it, grant yourself with the points and close the entry ?

Comment: Of course, here you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are form XObjects.

The pdf specification ISO 32000-1 characterizes them like this:

> A *form XObject* is a PDF content stream that is a self-contained description of any sequence of graphics objects. A form XObject may be painted multiple times - either on several pages or at several locations on the same page - and produces the same results each time, subject only to the graphics state at the time it is invoked.

For details please read section 8.10 of the specification.